# Im trying to understand how $= works in 1.0

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have been working with a checkbox component and i noticed different workflows for `checked$="{{model.isChecked}}"` vs `checked="{{model.isChecked}}"` and i wanted to know what the `$` actually does.

It seems there are some artifacts with the design.

Ideally, when it is checked it will toggle the value in `model`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding

`checked$="...."` binds to the attribute which is added to the DOM.

`checked="..."` binds to the property and only reflects to the attribute if `reflectToAttribute` is set to true (`https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties) or if it is a native property that reflects to an attribute.

See also [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Will either still set the value of the checkbox to the model?

Comment: Yes, elements usually read the attribute value into their properties and change their internal state accordingly.